# Ordenar do mais recente para o mais antigo no firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Atualmente eu estou conseguindo ordenar as publicações por data, mas como elas foram salvas por timestamp, ela é sempre exibida da mais antiga para a mais nova, gostaria de realizar o inverso, com as publicações mais novas primeiro.
Segue abaixo meu código atual:

```
        database.ref("Pedidos").orderByChild("data_pedido").on('child_added', function(snapshot){
```

Como a data esta sendo salva no banco:
[image: Imagem do banco do Firebase]

Grato pela atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme explicação neste [tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156996/firebase-data-desc-sorting-in-android/34158197#34158197) o firebase pode ordenar de forma crescente com a utilização em conjunto da função limitToFirst (n primeiros itens) ou limitToLast (n ultimos itens).

Para conseguir buscar em ordem decrescente, existem duas outras opções :

- Reordene os dados internamente no seu aplicativo.
- Crie um novo campo e armazene um timestamp com a ordem decrescente, exemplo:

  -1 * new Date().getTime();