# Ordenar ion-list por data

Tags: ionic, firebase, typescript

Bom dia, estou estudando IONIC com Firebase e criei uma lista simples onde quero que ela venha ordenada por data de atualização.
Na imagem podemos ver que a data está da mesma forma que veio do Firebase.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
pedidos:any

constructor(){
    // Initialize Firebase
  const config = {
    apiKey: "c",
    authDomain: "c",
    databaseURL: "c",
    projectId: "c",
    storageBucket: "c.c.c",
    messagingSenderId: "c"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  this.pedidos = new Array();

  let ref = firebase.database().ref('statuspedido').orderByChild('dataAtualizacao');//statuspedido
 ref.on('value', (dataSnapshot) =>{
     let items = dataSnapshot.val();
     for(let dados in items){
        this.pedidos.push(
            new PedidoModel(
                items[dados].idPedido,
                items[dados].dataEmissao,
                items[dados].dataAtualizacao,
                items[dados].vendedor,
                items[dados].frete,
                items[dados].transportadora,
                items[dados].status)
        )
     }
  })
}
```

e no firebase:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235413/ordenar-do-mais-recente-para-o-mais-antigo-no-firebase

Comment: leitura: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?hl=pt-br